# Движения блока по нажатию на определенную кнопку в Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Надо чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Влево" на клавиатуре, определенный блок двигался влево, но я никак не могу понять как это сделать, если знаете то пожалуйста помогите.Желательно это все сделать на JQuery.

Comment: это ответ не мой - а лишь пример как надо правильно задавать вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/845641/33274  смотрите ваше решение

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```js
let divBlock = $('.block');

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 68) //Right Arrow || D
    {
        let leftOffset = $(divBlock).offset().left;

        divBlock.css({
            left: (leftOffset + 5) + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;

    background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Надо чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Влево" на клавиатуре, определенный блок двигался влево. Желательно это все сделать на JQuery.

`jQuery animate` - как вариант.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  // Только при нажатии на > 
  if (e.which === 39) {
    // Moves left object
    $(".block").animate({
      marginLeft: "+=10px"
    }, "fast");
  }
})
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```

P.S: Надо кликнуть на объект или на окно в котором он отображается.