# Что я делаю не так в keydown?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

На вопрос меня толкнул [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/845491/33274) вопрос и так как не оказано должное внимание я решил это реализовать..Но что то не получилось

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("elem");

elem.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    elem.style.top = "30px"
  } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    elem.style.bottom = "-30px"
  } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    elem.style.left = "-30px"
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    elem.style.right = "-30px"
  }

}
```

```css
#elem {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Что я делаю не так ? Где ошибка ?

Для определения кода кнопки пользовался этим сервисом: http://keycode.info/

Общую информацию брал от сюда : https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: мои другие попытки здесь : http://jsfiddle.net/xwq5g20r/29/

Comment: К ответу @Igor можно лишь добавить, что причина в том, что у `div` по дефолту нет фокуса, соответственно и отслеживать нажатие кнопок для него невозможно, если по какой-то неведомой причине это все же хочется сделать, можно использовать атрибут `tabindex="1"`, тогда `div` можно будет зафокусить и соответственно отследить событие.

Comment: @MedvedevDev   не понял я ! если не ошибаюсь то вроде бы специально указываем какой элемент  будет под этой функцией , и работает без tabindex

Comment: если ты хочешь сделать именно так `elem.onkeydown` (где `elem` - `div`), то без `tabindex` не обойтись. `elem` должен быть чем-то, что имеет фокус (`window`, `document`, `input`, `textarea`, etc.)

Comment: @MedvedevDev  а почему тогда в этом случае работает ?

Comment: "в этом" - в ответе Igor? потому что он вешает слушатель на `document`, в твоих "других попытках" тоже работает по этой же причине. Здесь же в виджете событие отслеживается (пытается), с дива.

Comment: @MedvedevDev  наверно на window ? хотя спс что объяснили ....буду знать теперь ..

Comment: Для `onkeydown` не имеет значения на что вешать событие на `window` или `document` (оно всплывает), это имеет значение скажем для `onfocus`

Comment: @MedvedevDev вот кстати onFocus для меня эта тема не раскрыта но смотрел много примеров в сети и почему он работает ни как focus на css ?

Comment: что конкретно работает не так? Никогда вроде отличий не замечал (даже не задавался таким вопросом)

Comment: @MedvedevDev  я щас пока сделаю пример - отвечу минут через 10 -20 ok ?

Comment: Примеры - это хорошо xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev  вот к примеру это :http://jsfiddle.net/xwq5g20r/49/ как на js делать аналогично ..что бы кликнув вне  области панель пропадала ?

Comment: В js более однозначные события, по этому придется использовать 2: `focus` (получение фокуса), `blur` (снятие фокуса), по другому никак (http://jsfiddle.net/xwq5g20r/57/). Ситуация похожа на `hover` событие, в теории можно было бы соединить `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` и сделать одно событие (что собственно и сделали в jQuery, что кстати не особо то и удобно использовать), но в чистом js для каждого действия свое событие, а дальше делай с ними что хочешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, имелось в виду не присваивать одни и те же значения, а менять их.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("elem");

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
  var d = 2;
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    elem.style.top = (elem.offsetTop - d) + "px";
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    elem.style.top = (elem.offsetTop + d) + "px";
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    elem.style.left = (elem.offsetLeft - d) + "px";
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    elem.style.left = (elem.offsetLeft + d) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#elem {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Игорь ты гений ...........