# Плавное перемещение картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать плавное смещение изображения на определенное количество пикселей при нажатии, моментальное перемещение уже написал, теперь хочу сделать плавное, чтобы можно было скорость движения указать. Как это лучше сделать?

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img id="imgid" style="position: absolute; left: 10px" src="images/img.png">
</div>

<a href="" id="knopka">Переместить изображение</a>

<script>
knopka.onclick = function() {
var leftImage = 100;
document.getElementById("imgid").style.left = leftImage + 100 + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845633/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-keydown  этот вопрос похож ...посмотрите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте transition

```css
#imgid {
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
```

0.5s - время. Чем больше, тем медленнее движется.

А вообще, если по хорошему, не стоит двигать блок таким образом, это вызывает перерисовку страницы. Лучше использовать css трансформации

Comment: Не понял немного. Куда эту часть кода писать то?

Comment: @Holter, в css файл. Если такого не имеется, то в style.

Comment: Извините, я Вас не понял. У меня в функции js прописано смещение, при нажатии картинка смещается, но хотелось бы чтобы она двигалась плавно. Как мне совместить css с функцией?

Comment: @Holter,у вас для imgid уже прописаны стили в атрибуте style. Добавьте transition туда

Comment: Дело в том, что transition на определенный id устанавливается и только в одно сторону как я понимаю.

Comment: А я хочу добавить 4 кнопки и двигать анимацию в зависимости от нажатия кнопки.

Comment: Если будет transition:  left - всегда будет двигаться влево?

Comment: @Holter, transition: left  значит, что анимация будет применяться только для свойства left. Как я уже написал, вам лучше отказаться от сдвига таким образом, и перейти на трансформации, тем самым вы избавитесь от перерисовки, и получите возможность анимировать движение в любую сторону. https://webref.ru/css/transform

Comment: @Holter, если не сложно, отметьте ответ как решение.

Comment: Благодарю. Но, по-моему никакой перерисовки не происходит.